# Where does vote plugin update data in database on Joomla?

Tags: mysql, joomla, vote

Basic Joomla vote plugin:
`/plugins/content/vote/vote.php`

Does anybody know where and how votes of article are updated?
I have found a MySQL table called `#__content_rating`.

So, I do not understand, when somebody votes for article, how does this script `..vote/vote.php`
update data in table `#__content_rating`?

Anybody know? I tried to find it but was unsuccessful.

p.s. I am using Joomla! 2.5.0 Stable.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin file doesn't contain the store function. For this, you will have to go to:

`components/com_content/models/article.php`

The function starts on line 266 ( `public function storeVote($pk = 0, $rate = 0) {` )

However, unless you know exactly what you're doing, I wouldn't recommend changing core Joomla files. I would recommend you also update to the latest Joomla version (2.5.6) before any changes just in case you decide to update in the future and the update overrides that specific file.

Hope this helps

Comment: yes, this is what I needed. but it killed my theorem, how it is working ;/
I want to create a module - Most voted articles.
so, somehow I need to get information from two tables  `#__content_rating` and `#__content`. maybe you have ideas how to do that? :) any advice is very appreciated

Comment: @EdvaPtr - have you looked on [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org) for modules that may exist? If there is nothing there then I would recommend asking a new question.